# Large Malloc Array data lost after successful assigning it to memory

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I am trying to store large amount of data into multiple malloc array
I have three malloc array, two 2d char array and one int array. In a test case the array name are defined as:

```
cres=12163;
catm=41241;
matm = (char**) malloc(catm*sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<catm;i++)
      matm[i]=(char*) malloc(5*sizeof(char));
mres = (char**) malloc(cres*sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<cres;i++)
      mres[i]=(char*) malloc(5*sizeof(char));
mrin = (int*) malloc(cres*sizeof(int));
```

I read the data from a file. The data stored in these array if printed as it is stored in the these array is in right format. But when I try to retrieve data from the character arrays, after assigning value to the int array the character; array change the column length to 14 and the value is set to 8.50000000E-01.

I am using Linux Opensuse and g++ comiler.

Any Solution or alternate method to store large amount of data.

Sorry for all the confusion the blunder was on my part i was assigning the file-handling line pointer to all the values.

Comment: This should have been a "C" question rather than "C++". Adding a tag for `C` as well.

Comment: Try to use _valgrind_ or _gdb_ to debug what is going wrong or not expected.

Comment: This is bits and pieces of information. If you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be helpful for others in figuring out where the problem might be.

Comment: This is the worst question I have seen in a while.  Are you using C or C++, please pick ONLY 1.

Comment: @FlyingGuy: note that the OP said he is using a C++ compiler and tagged the question as C++.  Someone else added the `C` tag.

Comment: @iammilind "I am using Linux Opensuse and **g++** comiler." This is a C++ question. Why did you add a C tag?

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see. You only presented the memory allocation portion of the code, not the portion that actually experiences the problem.

Comment: i didnt add the c tag somebody else edited my tags

Comment: How do I attach the files from which i need to extract data. So that you could debug it or check it.

Answer (score 0):

So `matm` is an array of `char*` with length `catm`.  You then assign to its elements arrays of `char` of length 5.  Then you do the same for `res` instead of `atm`.

Finally, you allocate and store in `mrin` an array of `cres` integers.

Almost certainly you are overflowing one of these arrays.  You can use `valgrind` to figure out which, most likely automatically, by simply running `valgrind ./a.out` or whatever your program is called.  It will print stack traces where memory errors occur.

You may simply have strings longer than 4 characters (plus the terminating null).  You don't show the code where you populate the arrays.

Since you're using a C++ compiler, you should consider using C++ containers like `std::vector<char>` and `std::string` instead of raw C arrays which are error-prone as you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I am going to take a crack at this...  in C!

What you are making are arrays of pointers to char.

So two arrays of pointer to char, each holding 41241 pointers to char

One array holding pointers to int ( although why I have no idea since just declaring an array of int of size 12163 would do the trick.

Further you are declaring each entry on the char pointer array to be 5 chars which will hold a C style string of 4 bytes plus the null terminator.

```
char* strArray1 [41241] ;
char* strArray2 [41241] ;
int* intArray [12163] ;

for( int x=0 ; int < 41241;x++){
     strArray1[x] = malloc(5*sizeof(char)) ;
     strcopy("fred",strArray1[x]);
}

for( int x=0 ; int < 41241;x++){
     strArray2[x] = malloc(5*sizeof(char)) ;
     strcopy("Tom",strArray2[x]);
}

for(x=0;x<12163;x++){
     inArray[x*] = rand() % 50 ;
}

for( int x=0 ; int < 41241;x++){
     printf(" This entry = %s \n",strArray1[x]) ;
}

for( int x=0 ; int < 41241;x++){
     printf(" This entry = %s \n",strArray2[x]) ;
}

for( int x=0 ; int < 12163;x++){
     printf(" This entry = %i \n",intArray[x*]) ;
}
```

DO NOT try and get cute with C as it will bite you in the ass every time.

Comment: I usually mix c and c++ coding style in my programming sorry if it caused some confusion. I cant fix the array length, i mentioned earlier it is a test case. I am using namespace std after the header files. I dont like mentioning container every time. As i mentioned before the char arrays are assigned some value they lost("not replaced") their original content, If values to another malloc array is assigned. I am tring to ask is there any solution to this problem or i have to resort to other strategy inorder to solve this problem?

Comment: @SaadRaza You are losing me with "lost".  Data are not lost, the pointer to that data is either valid or not. IF you run this code twice without freeing up the memory allocated AND you are using C you are making memory leaks every time.  If you are counting on C++ to garbage collect, then you wont. Mixing C and C++ your asking for trouble.  As I said use one or the other.  Please explain what you mean by "lost".